# Как разделить данные тхт файла на два файла

Tags: python

Первый файл до :, а второй, после :. Пример:
отлично:Ну и супер
1-ый файл - Отлично
2-ой файл - Ну и супер

Comment: где проблемы? Считываем дальше `split()`, дальше перезаписываем содержимое файлов

Comment: При split(), обрабатывается только первая строчка, а их там более 1000

Comment: если строк много - `readlines()`, ну а дальше парсите список строк на свое усмотрение, как это делается я написал в ответе.

Answer (score 3):

насчет разделить - `stroke.split(':')`, где  `':'` это сам разделитель, можно делить по запятой, точке запятой, пробелу и т.д. А вот пример работы с файлами:

```py
x = open('file_name.txt') # открытие файла
x = x.readlines() # или readline() если строка в файле одна - счет данных из файла
x.write('file_name.txt') # запись в файл
```

ну а дальше сами

Comment: https://prnt.sc/qhxutl

Comment: @Bez_Name ошибка кодировки, это уже не ко мне)